# Is there an optimal way to insert a DateTime into an array C#

Tags: c#

I'm pretty new to C#, so any help is appreciated.

In the class of Courses I have following constructor:

```
public abstract class Courses
    {
        public DateTime CourseDate { get; set; }
        public int StreamID { get; private set; }
        public string CourseName { get; private set; }
        public int CourseID { get; private set; }
        public Courses(int courseID, int streamID, string courseName,DateTime courseDate)
        {
            this.CourseID = courseID;
            this.StreamID = streamID;
            this.CourseName = courseName;
            this.CourseDate = courseDate;
        }
    }
```

This is the array I'm trying to place the DateTime in.

```
Courses[] courses =
            {
                new Csharp(10, 3,"Basic C#", (11, 11, 10))
             }
```

the idea is that later on, I can cross check array items to make sure the courses aren't running on the same day

There will be upwards of lets say 10 items in the array example

If someone could assist me that would be amazing, or if it would be best to just have it set as a string for the sake of ease.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can not create an instance of `abstract` class

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar probably not. `Courses` is an abstract class, thus I assume from the context that `Csharp` inherits from it. OP just forgot a bit of code in the post.

Comment: @404, yeah that might be a case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using one of the many [`DateTime` constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor):

```
// set or replace year, month and day as desired
Courses[] courses =
{
    new Courses(10, 3, "Basic C#", new DateTime(year, month, day))
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various [constructors for DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1). For example, if you want to set year, month, day, hour, minute, second, you can use:

```
Courses[] courses =
            {
                new Csharp(10, 3,"Basic C#", new DateTime(2020, 6, 19, 15, 30, 0))
             }
```

This will create a course for June 19th, 2020 at 3:30 p.m.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! This is my first project so still learning the ropes :)

Answer (score 0):

That will not work, if you don't want to pass `new DateTime(11, 11, 10)` (as in year, month, day), you could create a specific constructor that has those values as separate arguments:

```
    public Courses(int courseID, int streamID, string courseName,
       int courseYear, int courseMonth, int courseDay)
    {
        this.CourseID = courseID;
        this.StreamID = streamID;
        this.CourseName = courseName;
        this.CourseDate = new DateTime(courseYear, courseMonth, courseDay);
    }
```

You need to provide this constructor in implementation classes (e.g. your `Csharp` class) as well, delegating to the base class.

Then you could do:

```
        Courses[] courses =
        {
            new Csharp(10, 3,"Basic C#", 11, 11, 10)
         }
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for this! This is my first project so still learning the ropes :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot create an instance of an `abstract` class. You can use this version of the constructor (year, month, day) to create `DateTime`. and you should pass the complete value for a year, not two digits. And it should not be `CSharp`.

```
Courses[] courses =
{
    new Courses(10, 3,"Basic C#", new DateTime(2011, 12, 29))
};
```